# a-frame navigation bar, that moves horizontal only

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality, aframe, webvr

I need to know, how to creat a navigation bar with a pre, home and next button.

The bar should be under the cursor and follow it horizontal. so that you can click on the button when you look down.

I have already the 3 buttons and they move the cursor, but now they should only move horizontal and not vertical.

```
<a-assets>

<a-mixin id="pre"  geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 0.1" material="color:blue; opacity:0.2"></a-mixin>
<a-mixin id="home" geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 0.1" material="color:green; opacity:0.2"></a-mixin>
<a-mixin id="next" geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 0.1" material="color:#fe0000; opacity:0.2"></a-mixin>

</a-assets>

<a-entity camera look-controls>
<a-cursor ></a-cursor> 
<a-entity mixin="pre" position="-0.2 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
<a-entity mixin="home" position="0.05 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
<a-entity mixin="next" position="0.3 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: it's working for me, i added a working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

When You put the entity inside the cursor, it will move exactly like the cursor, unless You make a script blocking it in the desired position.
 However in my opinion, you should create a entity consisting of the buttons:

```
<a-entity id="button_wrapper" position="0 0 -3" camera-check>
    <a-entity mixin="pre" position="-0.2 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
    <a-entity mixin="home" position="0.05 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
    <a-entity mixin="next" position="0.3 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
<a-entity id = "camera" camera look-controls>
    <a-cursor >
    </a-cursor>
</a-entity>
```

Having it this way, You can create a script moving the entity with the camera either moving the object when the camera changes, or moving it on tick():

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent('camera-check', {
  init: function () {
     var rotation;
     camera = document.querySelector('#camera');
     camera.addEventListener('componentchanged', function(evt) {
         if (evt.detail.name === 'rotation') {
         // here You have your new rotation reference in evt.detail.newData
         // and Your old rotation reference in evt.detail.oldData

         this.el.setAttribute("rotation","0 "+evt.detail.newData.y+" 0");
         }
     });
  },
  tick: function(){
    // this.el.setAttribute("rotation","0 "+document.querySelector('a-box').getAttribute("rotation").y)+" 0");
  }
});
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2v740m9/1/).